# Return only matched pattern from grep

Tags: r, regex

given the follwing example in R:

```
my.list<-list(a='ivw_2014_abc.pdf',b='ivw_2014_def.pdf',c='ivw_2014_ghi.pdf')

grep('(?<=ivw_2014_)[a-z]*',my.list,perl=T,value=T)
```

returns

```
                 a                  b                  c
"ivw_2014_abc.pdf" "ivw_2014_def.pdf" "ivw_2014_ghi.pdf"
```

I would like to make it return only

```
[1] 'abc' 'def' 'ghi'
```

in bash I would use the -o option. How do I achieve this in R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without using any capturing groups,

```
> my.list<-list(a='ivw_2014_abc.pdf',b='ivw_2014_def.pdf',c='ivw_2014_ghi.pdf')
> gsub("^.*_|\\..*$", "", my.list, perl=T)
[1] "abc" "def" "ghi"
```

Answer (score 2):

For example :

```
sub('.*_(.*)[.].*','\\1',my.list)
[1] "abc" "def" "ghi"
```

Answer (score 0):

Following may be of interest:

```
as.character(unlist(data.frame(strsplit(as.character(unlist(data.frame(strsplit(as.character(my.list),'\\.'))[1,])), '_'))[3,]))
[1] "abc" "def" "ghi"
```

Following is easier to read:

```
as.character(
    unlist(data.frame(strsplit(as.character(
        unlist(data.frame(strsplit(as.character(
            my.list),'\\.'))[1,])), '_'))[3,]))
[1] "abc" "def" "ghi"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be:

```
library(stringi)
stri_extract_first_regex(unlist(my.list), "[A-Za-z]+(?=\\.)")
#[1] "abc" "def" "ghi"
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the `regmatches` function.  It works with `regexpr` rather than `grep`, but returns just the matched part of the string.